# How do I go from sound to spectrum then back to sound in python?

Tags: python, audio, fft

How do I take a wav file, transform it into an array of frequency intensities every couple ms, do something with that array then transform that new array back into a wav file.

Is there a library that looks something like this

```
wav_data = library.read_wav('aoeu.wav') # [0, 3, 201, ... etc]

spectrum = library.get_spectrum(wav_data)  
# [[0, 0, 0, .2, 0, .7, ... etc], 
#  [0, 0, 0, .3, 0, .8, ... etc],
#  ... etc] 

spectrum[:, 0] = 0 # kill the lowest frequency (assuming spectrum is a numpy array)

library.spectrum_to_wav(spectrum) # [0, 3, 201, ... etc]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`librosa.stft`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html) and [`librosa.istft`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.istft.html) and read the audio file with [`librosa.load`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.load.html)

```
import librosa

audio, sample_rate = librosa.load('song.wav')

spectrum = librosa.stft(audio)
reconstructed_audio = librosa.istft(spectrum)

sum(audio[:len(reconstructed_audio)] - reconstructed_audio)  # very close to 0
```

I'm using `audio[:len(reconstructed_audio)]` because information is lost in the transform. `istft(stft(foo))` can return an array slightly shorter than `foo` and with slightly different values.